# QThread::wait blocks forever but ::run returns

Tags: qthread

I have a `QThread` subclass object with `::run()` overridden. There is while-loop inside like this:

```
void MyThread::run()
{
    while (true)
    {
        //do sth
        if (isInterruptionRequested())
        {
            //cleanup
            qDebug() << "fin";
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

When I go `thread->requestInterruption()` I'm getting the "fin" message so it works as expected. But if I add `thread->quit()` and `thread->wait()` there after requesting interruption in my main thread, it just waits indefinitely.
I know a proper way would be not to use the while loop but rely on Qt's inner loop and timers, but there is blocking `QSerialPort` management there I prefer over signals. Still, the `run()` returns so then it should go to the Qt's loop and finish, no?